# Why is my data not being stored to my firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to make a sign up page for a web app. This will send the data to the firebase database. I have read the official firebase docs and followed the intructions to write data. Yet nothing will write. In my database console, all it says is null, instead of my data. I am getting no console errors.

```
    <button id="signUpButton" onclick="confirmData()">Sign Up!</button>
    <script type="module" src="/backend/database.js"></script>
```

```
//import and initialize database
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDJdI7Sgr7ZGo3Do6NVswgs1UvjVcQUZbs",
  authDomain: "bakerstoolbox-9ca91.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://bakerstoolbox-9ca91-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "bakerstoolbox-9ca91",
  storageBucket: "bakerstoolbox-9ca91.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "175444196196",
  appId: "1:175444196196:web:f6314c643c71315b5f1871"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

//get user sign up data
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var phone = document.getElementById("phone-number");
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");

//button functions
const signUpButton = document.getElementById("signUpButton");
signUpButton.addEventListener("click", signUpNewUser);

//sign up a new user
function signUpNewUser(){
    set(ref(database, 'users/'), {
        userEmail : email,
        userPhoneNum : phone,
        userFirstName : firstName,
        userLastName : lastName
    });
    console.log("DEBUGGING")
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the result of `set()` for errors. Something could be going wrong and you'd never know.

Comment: How would I do that. This is my first time using fire base.

Comment: It returns a promise like any other JavaScript API.  Use that to check to see what happened.  Use the documentation as an example. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Comment: the check was succsesful yet no data is being stored.

Comment: What happens if you add a button type to your button, as follows: `<button type="button" id="signUpButton" onclick="confirmData()">Sign Up!</button>`?

Comment: I get the same thing, no data stored. I tried console logging all of the input fields when submitted to make sure they arent null and they are all correct and not null.

Comment: Your posts are [being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425393/what-happens-when-the-same-user-asks-the-same-question-twice)

Answer (score 6):

I feel that `email`, `phone-number`, `firstName`, and `lastName` are [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) elements, and since you want to retrieve their values, you have to use `value` attribute otherwise you'll get the actual HTML code, see below for more details.

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");

firstName.addEventListener("input", function () {
  console.log(firstName);
});

lastName.addEventListener("input", function () {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="firstName" />
<input id="lastName" />
```

And probably (highly guessing), Firebase isn't going to store HTML code so it switches to `null`.